# is typegraphql field generic object possible

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

Hi I am a bit of a newbie in typegraphql and graphql in general

so theres a thing that i want to change but to put it simply:

Current Working Code I want to change:

```
@ObjectType()
export class Game {
  @Field(() => Int)
  id: number;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  producedByUserName?: string;
  
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  producedByUserEmail?: string;
}
```

Code I want to achieve is something like this

```
@ObjectType()
export class Game {
  @Field(() => Int)
  id: number;

  producedByUserName?: string;
  producedByUserEmail?: string;

  @Field(type => Object, { name: 'producedBy', nullable: true }) // i also tried Record<string, string>
  producedBy(){
    return {
      email: this.producedByUserEmail,
      name: this.producedByUserName,
    }
  }
}
```

I am wondering if I could achieve something like this.

i tried the code above and its always throwing
CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for 'producedBy' of 'Game' class.

Comment: The return type of `producedBy` function must be an `ObjectType` or a `ScalarType` known to `graphql`. A generic _JS_ object is not known to `GraphQL`

Comment: PS: If you want a set of pre-defined custom scalars take a look at [`graphql-scalars`](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars)